# Getting around circular dependency of Android modules?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, module

I have multiple modules in my android project some of which depend on other modules however I have a couple of cases where modules depend each other thus creating a circular dependency?

How would you generally go about avoiding such cases in an android or java project? In my case I am using Intellij Idea 13.1.2 if that makes any difference?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your design is broken and needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot design modules with circular dependency.If it persist you can merge the dependent code into single module to avoid circular dependency.

Answer (score 3):

There is no magic. You need to redesign your model. Experience and application.